# Knights tour animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

[image]

Is it possible to create the above animation? I have taken this from Numberphile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
usepackage("skak");
unitsize(1cm);
void chessboard(int n=3, pen color1= currentpen, pen color2= white)
{
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i){
    for (int j=0; j < n; ++j){
      fill(shift(j,i)*unitsquare, (i%2 ==0 && j%2 == 0) ? color1 : color2);
      if (i%2 !=0 && j%2 != 0) { fill(shift(j,i)*unitsquare, color1); }
    }
  }
}
chessboard(8,darkgreen,white);
pair pos(pair A){ return (A+(A-(1,1)))/2; }
path[] Lpath=texpath("$\BlackKnightOnWhite$");
picture pic;
filldraw(pic,Lpath,white,black+0.3bp);
add(scale(1.5)*pic,pos((3,5)));
pair[] Pos={(8,8),(7,6),(6,8),(8,7),(7,5),(5,6),(4,8),(2,7),(1,5),(3,6),(2,8),(1,6)};
pair[] listofpostions;
for( pair A : Pos){ listofpostions.push(pos(A));}
draw(operator -- (... listofpostions),red+1.5bp);
for (int i=0; i < listofpostions.length ; ++i)
{
  label(scale(2)*Label("$"+ (string) (i+1) +"$",gray),listofpostions[i]);
}
```

[image]

```
import animate;
usepackage("skak");
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 
settings.outformat="pdf"; 

animation Ani;

unitsize(1cm);
void chessboard(int n=3, pen color1= currentpen, pen color2= white)
{
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i){
    for (int j=0; j < n; ++j){
      fill(shift(j,i)*unitsquare, (i%2 ==0 && j%2 == 0) ? color1 : color2);
      if (i%2 !=0 && j%2 != 0) { fill(shift(j,i)*unitsquare, color1); }
    }
  }
}
chessboard(8,darkgreen,white);

pair pos(pair A){ return (A+(A-(1,1)))/2; }
pair[] Pos={(8,8),(7,6),(6,8),(8,7),(7,5),(5,6),(4,8),(2,7),(1,5),(3,6),(2,8),(1,6)};
pair[] listofpostions;
for( pair A : Pos){ listofpostions.push(pos(A));}

path[] Lpath=texpath("$\BlackKnightOnWhite$");
picture pic;
filldraw(pic,Lpath,white,black+0.3bp);
guide g;
for (int i=0; i < listofpostions.length ; ++i){
save();
g=g--listofpostions[i];
draw(g,(i != 0) ? red+1.5bp : invisible);
add(scale(1.5)*pic,listofpostions[i]);
Ani.add();
restore();
label(scale(2)*Label("$"+ (string) (i+1) +"$",gray),listofpostions[i]);
}
erase();
chessboard(8,darkgreen,white);
draw(g,red+1.5bp);
for (int i=0; i < listofpostions.length ; ++i){
label(scale(2)*Label("$"+ (string) (i+1) +"$",gray),listofpostions[i]);
}
add(scale(1.5)*pic,pos((3,5)));
Ani.add();
erase();
Ani.movie();
```

[image]

Comment: Cant thank you enough. Thanks a ton for this wonderful answer.

Comment: Hey the animate command doesn't seem to run on that webpage. Could you please help.

Answer (score 5):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes!

It is created with a trick stolen from [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552203/87876).

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\newcommand\obj{\rput(.5,.5){\tikz[scale=.35]\duck;}}

\begin{document}
\let\CUMULATIVE\undefined
\foreach \k in {0/0,2/3,4/4,3/6,1/7,2/5,3/3,2/1}{
  \xdef\CUMULATIVE{\ifdefined\CUMULATIVE \CUMULATIVE,\fi \k}
  \begin{pspicture}(8,8)
    \psframe[dimen=i,linewidth=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,linecolor=brown](8,8)
    \multips(0,0)(0,2){4}{%
      \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{%
        \multips(0,0)(1,1){2}{\psframe*(1,1)}}}    
        \pscustom[linecolor=red,linewidth=3pt,linejoin=1]{%
            \moveto(.5,.5)%
            \foreach \i/\j in \CUMULATIVE {\lineto(!\i\space .5 add \j\space .5 add)}}
        \foreach \i/\j in \CUMULATIVE {\rput(\i,\j){\obj}}
  \end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first movement from the initial position is wrong by design.

Comment: +1 You can fix "the first movement"!?

Comment: @Chishimotoji: I left it as it is for your exercise. :-)

Comment: @TooFatManNoNeck The numbers aren't shown? In my animation as soon as the knight moves from the first square the square is marked as 1. How can we achieve this? Also once the knight has left the square i just want the numbers to be shown and not the knight

Comment: @TooFatManNoNeck Thanks also for this answer :)

Comment: @TooFatManNoNeck Can you upvote my answer? :-)

Comment: @user213378: I don't know how to upvote. Please make an animation showing the steps.