# How to use nested \foreach when the range of the inner one is given by the outer one?

Tags: pstricks, pgffor

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,12pt]{standalone}

\def\obj{%
    \pscircle[linecolor=yellow](.5,.5){12pt}
    \pscircle[linecolor=cyan](.5,.5){11pt}}
    
\begin{document}
\foreach \k in {%
    {0/0},
    {0/0,2/3},
    {0/0,2/3,4/4}
    }{%
\begin{pspicture}(8,8)
    \psframe[dimen=i,linewidth=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,linecolor=brown](8,8)
    \multips(0,0)(0,2){4}{%
        \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{%
            \multips(0,0)(1,1){2}{\psframe*(1,1)}}}
    \foreach \i/\j in \k {\rput(\i,\j){\obj}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

A bonus question:

Is there any trick to simplify the following

```
{0/0},
{0/0,2/3},
{0/0,2/3,4/4}
```

into just a single `{0/0,2/3,4/4}` but the outer loop still works as if it is still working on

```
{0/0},
{0/0,2/3},
{0/0,2/3,4/4}
```

?

Comment: I don't find `\dimexpr355pt/113` particularly fun. Use `border=3` and you'll have less problems.

Comment: @egreg:  I am very impressed with the ratio 355/113. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `\foreach` buries each cycle inside a group.

```latex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3,12pt]{standalone}

\newcommand\obj{%
  \pscircle[linecolor=yellow](.5,.5){12pt}%
  \pscircle[linecolor=cyan](.5,.5){11pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\let\CUMULATIVE\undefined
\foreach \k in {0/0,2/3,4/4}{
  \xdef\CUMULATIVE{\ifdefined\CUMULATIVE \CUMULATIVE,\fi \k}%
  \begin{pspicture}(8,8)
    \psframe[dimen=i,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=brown](8,8)
    \multips(0,0)(0,2){4}{%
      \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{%
        \multips(0,0)(1,1){2}{\psframe*(1,1)}%
      }%
    }
    \foreach \i/\j in \CUMULATIVE {\rput(\i,\j){\obj}}
  \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

I used an uncommon command name just to ensure that nothing important gets redefined.

Answer (score 2):

Just spitballing here, I don't have a LaTeX installation handy at the moment, but perhaps something along the lines of

```
\newcounter{foo}
\foreach \k in {1,2,3}{
  \setcounter{foo}{0}
  \foreach \j in {{(0,0)},{(2,3)},{(4,4)}}{
     \stepcounter{foo}
     \ifnum\value{foo}<\k
        do stuff with \j
     \fi
  }
}
```

I offer no guarantees about off by one errors or whether the wrapping (a,b) in braces will work (but it should and I'm pretty sure my math is right. You could also do

```
\ifnum\value{foo}=\k
   \breakforeach
\fi
do stuff with \j
```

which would be mildly more efficient but feels kind of 1980s code to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools,multido}
\def\obj{%
    \pscircle[linecolor=yellow](.5,.5){12pt}
    \pscircle[linecolor=cyan](.5,.5){11pt}}    

\psRegisterList{No}{{0,0},{2,3},{4,4}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{3}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(8,8)
    \psframe[dimen=i,linewidth=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,linecolor=brown](8,8)
    \multips(0,0)(0,2){4}{%
        \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{%
            \multips(0,0)(1,1){2}{\psframe*(1,1)}}}
  \multido{\iB=1+1}{\iA}{\rput(\No{\iB}){\obj}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```